# How to get all elements with class name in list form in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jinja2

I have multiple email inputs:

```
<input type="text" class="email" value="{{email}}">
```

And I want to retrieve each email input and put them all in one list:

```
var names = $(".email").val();
```

But right now I only get the first value instead of the full list. What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$.map` to create an array of the values.

```
var names = $.map($(".email"), function(e) {return e.value});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.each function will help you,

var email array = [];

```
jQuery(".email").each(function{
  email_array[email_array.length] = jQuery(this).val();
  #you can any operation in this block
});
```

now, you have all email in email_array

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're looking for a string list?

Try the "each" function!

```
var names = "";
$(".email").each(function(){
    if(names != ""){
       names += ", ";
    }
    names += $(this).val();
});

console.log(names);
```